# $(x + 3)(ax^2 + bx + c) = x^3 - 2x^2 + 3$ yields ambiguous $c$ values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In lieu of synthetic division for solving the problem of $\frac{x^3 - 2x^2 + 3}{x + 3}$, I opted for using simultaneous equations to solve $(x + 3)(ax^2 + bx + c) = x^3 - 2x^2 + 3$, though in due course, I did solve that $a = 1; b = -5$, but upon trying to find $c$, I faced the predicament of having two contradictory equations:

$(x+3)(ax^2 + bx + c) = ax^3 + x^2(b + 3a) + x(c + 3b) + 3c = x^3 - 2x^2 + 3 \\ a = 1 \implies x^3 + x^2(b + 3) + x(c + 3b)
\\ b + 3 = -2 \implies (b = -5) \land (c - 5*3 = 0 \implies c = 15) \\
\text{but } 3c = 3 \implies c = 1 \\
15 \neq 1$

So, I notice that $(x+3)$ doesn't divide the given cubic by the remainder theorem, but I'm confused on how I should approach solving for $c$ if it is known that there is a remainder. Is there a similar algebraic approach, or intuition?

Comment: We *can't* solve $x^3 -2x^2 +3 = (x+3)(ax^2 +bx +c)$ but we *CAN* solve for  $x^3 -2x^2 +3 = (x+3)(ax^2 +bx +c)+d$.  You have to add that $3c+d =3$; *not* $3c = 3$

Comment: In other words add a variable $d$ to be the remainder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, I notice that (x+3) doesn't divide the given cubic by the remainder theorem

... then we must conclude $x+3$ is not a divisor of $x^3 - 2x^2+3$

and $x^3 -2x^3 + 3$ can not factor with $x+3$ being a factor

.....  And if you think about it, there was no reason we should have thought it would.

> but I'm confused on how I should approach solving for c if it is known that there is a remainder.

You *can't* solve for $c$ because $(x+3)(ax^2 + bx+c) = x^2 -2x^2 +3$ doesn't *have* any solutions.

But we *CAN* solve for

$x^3 - 2x^2 + 3 = (x+3)(ax^2 +bx+c) + d$ where $d$ is the remainder.

We get $a = 1$  $b+3a = -2$ and $c+3b = 0$ and $3c + d = 3$.

So $a = 1$ and $b = -5$ and $c = 15$ and .....  $d=3-3*15=-42$.

.......

Synthetic division will confirm as we will have are remainder.  $\frac {x^3 - 2x^2+3}{x+3} = \frac {x^3+3x^2}{x+3} + \frac {-5x^2 - 15x}{x+3} + {15x + 45}{x+3} - \frac {42}{x+3} = x^2 -5x + 15- \frac {42}{x+3}$ or $x^3 - 2x^2 + 3 = (x+3)(x^2 -5x + 15) -42\ne (x+2)(ax^2 + bx +c)$ for any possible values of $a,b$ or $c$.

Ta-da!

Comment: thank you! that makes a lot more sense now, i suppose i just forgot to generalize the equation even more to account for remainders, i tried it out where the divisor does factor into the equation and the `d` constant becomes `0` just as expected. beautiful; again, thanks.